# IF function to check multiple conditions on same range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight cells depend on the cell value.

If it is a single value I can do it with the IF function. I am trying to identify whether the value is either "9900" or ""9100". Cam someone please explain me where I get this wrong? (I know it is the first line of the code)

```
If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9900" Or "9100" Then
    Range("A" & i & ":" & "L" & i).Select
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to highlight it, if the value is neither 9900 nor 9100, then it's

```
If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9900" And Range("E" & i).Value <> "9100" Then
```

The other way around it's

```
If Range("E" & i).Value = "9900" Or Range("E" & i).Value = "9100" Then
```

Comment: Because this is the same Range we are checking, it wont do the job for me. What it actually does is highlight all the ones that not equal to "9900".

Comment: @Isu: `If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9900" And Range("E" & i).Value <> "9100" Then` behaves identical to `If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9900" Then
  If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9100" Then`.

Comment: @Isu -  Is it `"9100"` and `"9900"` or `9100` and `9900`? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Actually I do not know the difference. They are in number format 9900 and 9100.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found,

```
If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9900" Then
  If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9100" Then
    Range("A" & i & ":" & "L" & i).Select
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
    End If
```

Answer (score -1):

```
last_row = Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row


Range("A" & last_row & ":" & "L" & last_row).Select

 With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16711681
    .TintAndShade = 0
    End With



If Range("E" & i).Value <> "9900" Or "9100" Then
Range("A" & i & ":" & "L" & i).Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
Next i
```